# PyQt5 file missing (PyQt noob)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyuic

I have a study assignment due that requires me to convert a `*.ui` file from Qt into a `*.py` file using the command prompt.
However I have been struggling because I can not find the Pyuic5/4 module used to convert a `*.ui` file into a `*.py` file.
{I have literally dug through and searched for it in my drive and can not find it}

I have the mots recent Qt and Python download and running well.

Any help or alternative method to converting `*.ui` to `*.py` would really be appreciated!

Comment: What platform are you on, and how did you install pyqt?

Comment: I am using PyQt GPL v5.4.1 for Python v3.4 (x64). It seems the install I have did not manage to include the pyuic file at al and I had to find it and set it in the Qt folder in my drive. And odd procedure but it seems to do the trick, though I am not comfortable with it as the conversion in the command prompt usually does not succeed. If feels like a patchwork solution for some odd reason. I am running on Windows 7 and I installed it via the Qt website.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `pip install pyuic5-tool` in your terminal.